# Do subject-object-verb language users perceive the world differently than SVO or VSO users?

Tags: sentences, sapir-whorf-hypothesis

So based on linguistic relativity, I'm wondering if there are any ways that people perceive the world differently based on sentence order, or rather, if this has even been studied at all?

Comment: Basically, the question is scientifically unaskable since there is no way to measure anything as broad as "how people perceive the world".

Comment: You may find it interesting to read about [Sapir-Whorf Hypothesis](https://linguistlist.org/ask-ling/sapir.cfm). There's also a tag [tag:sapir-whorf-hypothesis] here with several interesting questions asked and answered.

Comment: SOV systems constitute around half the world's languages and share many features; SOV seems to be a grammatical saddle-point -- a very stable system that works in a number of situations and satisfies a number of requirements. That's an interesting fact in itself. But asking about thought processes is the wrong question, since any two humans "perceive the world differently", no matter what languages they speak. That is, individual variation in thought patterns is orders of magnitude more significant than language variation, which gets swamped by comparison.

Comment: @johnlawlerinexile Which of course doesn't preclude there being any discernible and quantifiable variation in thought patterns in correlation with word order.

Comment: @MaxP: Yes it does, because "thought patterns" are not discernible and quantifiable, and therefore can't be correlated with anything that is. "Thought pattern" is hand-waving; it means whatever we intend it to mean.

Comment: @johnlawlerinexile How are they not quantifiable? I can hand out questionnaires asking people to rate on a scale how much they identify with a given thought and evaluate them. I call that quantifiable. I will agree with you if you tell me that there can be a lot of subjectivity in the evaluation and design of the questionnaires and that most studies done that way on that topic might be bogus, but that doesn't mean that it can't be done in a scientific way.

Comment: @bytebuster Linguistic relativity is a synonym for the Sapir-Whorf Hypothesis. I'll have to add the tag though, thanks.

Comment: @Max P: handing people a questionnaire and asking people to pick a number doesn't constitute a "quantification" or a property, unless the property causes the response. There are no even marginally credible correlations between constituent order any any behavioral test. There is more to scientifically asking a question than proposing a mechanical operation (see Eddington 1938 *et seq.*).

Comment: @user6726 and there are ways to control that other properties haven't influenced the property. And excluding possible outcomes from the beginning because you aren't going to believe them anyways doesn't strike me as very scientific either. Of course I expect that if you actually did such a survey and did it well, it would show that there is indeed no correlation, but even that is an outcome. If you are right, there is no possible outcome of such a study, because the question can't be asked scientifically.

Comment: @MaxP, the best way to see why you can't control those influences is to construct the questionnaire, state the hypothesis being tested, and say how your questions have controlled other variables. Not every "idea" constitutes a scientifically testable hypothesis. This is an invitation -- try to construct the questionnaire.